# Justify dynamically written text when using "white-space: pre-wrap"

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with a detail on a project and I can't see any solution. We're getting datas writen by an Ai from a MySQL bdd and showing them as text in a fancy way http://82.223.18.239/writing.php

As you can see, the text isn't properly justified in the begining, it is when the writing process hit the bottom of the page, and I don't know how to fix this. When "white-space: pre-wrap" isn't used, everything work fine but I lose the line jump. Any help ?

Our wip code

```
<head>
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="body"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>

    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css"> 
        #myTable{ 
           width:"90%";
           min-width:250px;
           white-space: pre-wrap;
           word-wrap:break-word;
           position:absolute;
           border:solid 0px;
           top:200px;
           left:720px;
           right:720px;
           bottom:50px;
           font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
           text-align:justify
        } 

        #body       {
            padding-bottom:60px;
            height:2px;
                   }

   </style> 

</head>

<body>
    <div id="myTable"> <div>

    <script type="text/javascript">  
        var skip = 0;
        function get_data(index) {
            $.ajax({
                url : 'getData.php',
                type : 'POST',
                data: ({"skip":skip}),
                success : function(data) { 
                    if(data && data.trim()!='') {
                        skip = skip+1;
                        showText("#myTable", data, 0, 2); 
                    }
                    else {
                        setTimeout(function () { get_data(skip); }, 30000);
                    }
                },
                error : function(request,error)
                {
                    alert("Request error : "+JSON.stringify(request));
                }
            });
        }

        function showText(target, message, index, interval) {   
            if (index < message.length) {
                $(target).append(message[index++]);
                setTimeout(function () { showText(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
            }
            else {
                get_data(skip);
            }
        }

        //var period = 10000; //NOTE: period is passed in milliseconds
        get_data(skip);
        //setInterval(page_refresh, period); 
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: `text-align: justify` will only justify the text if it fills the entire line, and then it will adjust the spacing between the words so that the last letter is justified. But if the text doesn't fill up the whole line, it won't justify.

Comment: I know, but why it wait until more than twenty lines are written before suddenly changing the entire shape of the text ?